# Difficulty with 'group_by' in Polars

Tags: time-series, kaggle

I am new to polars, trying to convert my pandas code to polars.

The below code is in pandas, (book --> pd.DataFrame)

```
book = load_data(0 ,'book' ,DataBlock.TRAIN)
book['wap1'] = calc_wap1(book)
book['wap2'] = calc_wap2(book)
x = book.groupby(['time_id'])['wap1'].apply(log_return)
book.shape, x.shape
```

Output : `((917553, 12), (917553,))`

I tried to write the following code in polars (book -> polars.DataFrame):

```
book = load_book(0, block=DataBlock.TRAIN)
book = book.with_columns(pl.lit(calc_wap1(book)).alias("wap1"))
book = book.with_columns(pl.lit(calc_wap2(book)).alias("wap2"))

def log_return(wap1_series):
    """Calculates the log returns of a given wap1 Series."""
    log_wap1 = wap1_series.log()  # Take the log of wap1
    log_returns = log_wap1.diff()  # Calculate the difference (log returns)
    return log_returns

log_returns_df = book.groupby("time_id").agg(
    log_return_wap1=pl.col("wap1").apply(log_return)
)
log_returns_df.shape
```

Output :  `(3830, 2)`

```
log_returns_df.head(2)

3567    [null, -0.000222, … 0.0]
27153   [null, 0.000013, … 0.0]
```

I don't want this array, I need log_returns_df such that it can be added as new feature in book.

All the functions mentioned above are defined in code_base...
Please guide on how to approach this problem... Thank in advance